# Find all functions such that $f(xy+f(x))=f(f(x)f(y))+x$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

I am looking for all functions $f:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ that satisfy for all $x,y>0$: $$f(xy+f(x))=f(f(x)f(y))+x.$$

I found that $f(x)=x$ works. Are there other solutions?

I try setting $x=1$: $$f(y+f(1))=f(f(1)f(y))+1$$ and swapping $x,y$ to get $$f(xy+f(x))-f(xy+f(y))=x-y.$$ Now I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Sumanta Only **$x>0$ and $y>0$** are allowed

Comment: you can disprove $f(x) = x^p, p \neq 1$ and $f(x) = ax$, $f(x)=x+b$ by counter example

Comment: Is this a problem from a textbook or did you come up with this problem yourself?

Comment: @user729882 See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3435592/hard-functional-equation-function), where in the comments I've posted a source.

Comment: The problem is (reportedly) from Brazilian math Olympiad 2019, according to [the same problem 21 days ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3435592/hard-functional-equation-function)

Answer (score 1):

$f(xy+f(x)) =f(f(x)f(y)) + x$

$f(xy+f(y))=f(f(x)f(y)) + y$

Subtracting with $y=0$
$f(f(x))=x+f(f(0))$

Now $f$ is bijective.
Plugging $y=0$ again
$f(f(x)) =x+f(f(x)f(0))$

Hence $f(0)=0$ because $f$ is bijective and $f(f(0))=f(f(x)f(0))$

$f(f(x)) =x$

Put $x=c$ such that $f(c) =1$, and $y:=y-c$
$f(cy+1-c^2)=y=f(f(y))$

$cy+1-c^2=f(y)$

$f(x) = cx+1-c^2$